# Fixed content header with a flexbox layout that has scrollable content area

Tags: css, flexbox

I want the Content Header to be fixed so the content scrolls underneath.  This is a classic holy grail layout using flexbox with scrollable content area.

I have tried setting the Content Header to fixed position and adding padding this works sort of but then it does not take up the full width of the content area.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.holy-grail {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.holy-grail-body {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;

}

.holy-grail-content {
    flex: 1;
    background: #ffc94e;
    overflow: auto;
}

.holy-grail-content-header {
    background: lightyellow;
  height: 50px;
}

.holy-grail-nav, .holy-grail-sidebar {
    /* 12em is the width of the columns */
    flex: 0 0 12em;
    background: #c9ea5d;
}

.holy-grail-nav {
    /* put the nav on the left */
    order: -1;
    background: #85d6e4;
}

header {
    background: #92e4c9;
}

footer {
    background: #f7846a;
}

* {
    color: #333;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>A Holy Grail Flexbox layout</title>


</head>
<body class="holy-grail">
<header>
    <h1>Header</h1>
</header>
<div class="holy-grail-body">
    <main class="holy-grail-content">
      <header class="holy-grail-content-header">Content Header</header>
        TEST
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
    </main>
    <nav class="holy-grail-nav">
        <h2>Navigation</h2>
    </nav>
    <aside class="holy-grail-sidebar">
        <h2>Sidebar</h2>
    </aside>
</div>
<footer>
    <h2>Footer</h2>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you use `position: fixed`?

Comment: @Oriol, what else should I use to allow the content to scroll under the header?

Comment: Not sure why this is marked as on hold by @George Stocker.  I have two solid code examples of what I am trying to achieve, the first example shows what I am trying to achieve using current methods, the second is my attempt to achieve the same layout as the first example but using flexbox instead, with the specific problem I am having which is with the header overlapping the scroll bar since the header is fixed position

Comment: @dan The close message is very specific; You should provide the shortest amount of code necessary to reproduce the problem. You have way too much code here.

Comment: @ George Stocker, the only really part of the code that I can think of removing would be the few elements in the top nav, but it is not that much, otherwise as far as my skills go everything else is needed to demonstrate the layout I am trying to achieve and the problem with that layout.  So as far as I am able I have always tried to use a minimal code to demonstrate my questions or answers, thanks

Comment: @George Stocker No the close message is not very clear at all!  It lists several possible issues, ie must have a desired behavior, specific problem or error and shortest code necessary.  No way for me to know why you closed it until you told me that it was specifically shortest code necessary issue, which I have explained in previous comment as it is the shortest I can make it and still demonstrate my problem, thanks

Comment: @dan Not sure what else should you use instead of `position: fixed`, because I don't know which is the desired result. There are too many elements in the snippet, please create a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And your "original version" and "flexbox version" are completely different. Are you attempting to make the flexbox one look like the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, maybe there is a better solution, comments are welcome, but this seems to work.  I basically made another flexbox column for the content then added a header, this works the same way as the outer flexbox column header, content, footer.

Below is the completed code

```css
html, body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}


.holy-grail {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.holy-grail-body {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.holy-grail-content {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    background: #ffc94e;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    order: 2;
}

.holy-grail-content-header {
    background: lightyellow;
    flex: 0 0 50px;
}

.content {
    flex: 1;
    overflow:auto;
}

.holy-grail-nav, .holy-grail-sidebar {
    /* 12em is the width of the columns */
    flex: 0 0 10em;
    background: #c9ea5d;
}

.holy-grail-nav {
    /* put the nav on the left */
    order: 1;
    background: #85d6e4;
}
.holy-grail-sidebar {
    order: 3;
}
header {
    background: #92e4c9;
    height: 50px;
    
}

footer {
    background: #f7846a;
    height: 50px;

}

* {
    color: #333;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>A Holy Grail Flexbox layout</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body class="holy-grail">
<header>
    <h1>Header</h1>
</header>
<div class="holy-grail-body">
    <main class="holy-grail-content">
      <header class="holy-grail-content-header">Content Header</header>
        <div class="content">TEST
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A animi aut distinctio dolor eaque enim fuga labore perspiciatis unde? Accusamus atque consectetur eaque et modi molestias provident ratione reprehenderit ullam.
        TestEnd
        </div>
    </main>
    <nav class="holy-grail-nav">
        <h2>Navigation</h2>
    </nav>
    <aside class="holy-grail-sidebar">
        <h2>Sidebar</h2>
    </aside>
</div>
<footer>
    <h2>Footer</h2>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```